# UIDatePicker questions regarding displaying

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidatepicker

Does anyone know if it's possible to change the minute interval of a UIDatePicker after it's been added to a UIView? Is it possible to show and hide 2 different datePickers? I want change the minuteInterval of the UIDatePicker to 5 and 30 when I click a button. Any sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything you asked is possible... here's how:

```
#import "DateStuffAppDelegate.h"

@implementation DateStuffAppDelegate

@synthesize window;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    d = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] init] retain];
    d.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, d.frame.size.width, d.frame.size.height);

    d.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    d.countDownDuration = 10.0;
    d.minuteInterval = 1;

    [window addSubview: d];


    d1 = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] init] retain];
    d1.frame = CGRectMake(0, d.frame.size.height, d1.frame.size.width, d1.frame.size.height);

    d1.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    d1.countDownDuration = 10.0;
    d1.minuteInterval = 1;

    [window addSubview: d1];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}



- (IBAction)doStuff
{
    d.minuteInterval = 5;

    d1.hidden = !d1.hidden;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```